# How to determine the URI of a google BigQuery project

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am trying to determine a Bigquery URI from my project to write from google Apps Script to Bigquery. However, I have been unable to find the source to put into my configurations. How do I find the BIgquery URI (gs://bucket_name/specific_location)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

gs:// locations refer to Google Cloud Storage, not Google BigQuery. BigQuery can read and output to and from any arbitrary gs:// location.

In the console for your project (https://cloud.google.com/console), you will be able to create a GCS location with any unique name you might choose.